# XUL - firefox last downloaded file

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

Is there a simple way to get the name of the last file downloaded from a xul app for firefox?

I want to get this file and post it to a url of my choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Downloads.jsm JavaScript code module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm)

You need to import the module with:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm");
```

You can then obtain the download list:

```
var list = Downloads.getList(Downloads.ALL);
```